# Splitting a string causing GUI to crash?

Tags: python

I have the following code which for some reason is causing the Python GUI to crash at the line print:

```
urlstr = str(URLS)
        a = urlstr.split('=', 2)
        print('a=', a)
```

URLS is a URL generated from a dictionary, which is in turn created from the values of a series of text files. I am making a string from URLS then trying to split it at the second equals sign.

If I remove the print statement the code runs fine, but the conditional logic that 'a' is passed to does not produce a value.

Can anyone see what the issue is as I am really confused.

Thanks

Comment: Put a `try..except` around the `split` and print the exception

Comment: im not sure it will produce one as it causes the GUI to literally freeze completely...

Comment: `split` doesn't do what you think it does; `split("=", 2)` will split on the *first two* equals, not the second one, i.e. give a list of (up to) three items.

Comment: ah right. what would the syntax for splitting on the second equals be?

Comment: There is no such syntax. If it is also the last equals, you could use `rsplit("=", 1)`

Comment: it is the last one. i will try that and see how i get on. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the IDLE Python shell and threads. Correct me if I am wrong.

Sometimes this causes Tkinter/the IDLE to crash.

Here is some code I wrote in 2008 to prevent the Python Shell from crashing when using threads.

```
## das muss in idlelib.PyShell in die letzten Zeilen der Klasse
## this must be copied  to idlelib.PyShell into the last lines of the class


#############################  adds by nicco kunzmann  #########################

    __nk___init__= __init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        self.__nk___init__(*args, **kw)
        self.__nk_writelist= []
        self.__nk_act_act_write()

    __nk_write= write
    def write(self, *args):
        self.__nk_writelist.append(args)

    def __nk_act_act_write(self):
        try:
            while self.__nk_writelist:
                args= self.__nk_writelist.pop(0)
                try:
                    self.__nk_write(*args)
                except:
                    traceback.print_exception(*sys.exc_info())
                    print args

        finally:
            self.text.after(1, self.__nk_act_act_write)


#############################  adds  by  n.k. the end  #########################
```